# Proper way to add ojdbc8.jar to Eclipse/maven project

Tags: oracle, eclipse, maven, jdbc, pom.xml

Just joined a company (and an existing project) and first blocker is getting Eclipse/maven/pom.xml to recognize I do actually have the ojdbc8.jar file on my system. Eclipse/maven/pom.xml disagree. When looking at the pom.xml file, Eclipse says "Missing artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:12.2.0.1"

I have tried adding the jar to the "Referenced Libraries". No joy.

I have tried installing maven and then the jar into the maven repo ([see this link](https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/)) which ran fine, but Eclipse/maven still say the artifact is missing.

I guess because Eclipse uses it's own maven repo, but I don't know how to add a jar file to it, or if that is even the right way to do this. ** After reading some more, it appears I have been misled and Eclipse does not have it's own maven repo?**

I also found [this](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9010) at Oracle's website, but it seems like a lot of steps and I already added the jar to my local repo so I don't expect it to help.

I have tried asking my co-worker. No response...

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Eclipse uses the same local repository as everything else. Unless you configured a different settings.xml in the m2e options. It is important that you actually *build* the project in Eclipse, i.e. something like `clean verify`. The red bubbles in the Eclipse IDE sometimes show errors that do not really exist.

Comment: You can get it even from Maven Central Repo: https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides

Comment: Even up to v21.1: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/

Answer (score 0):

So I found [this page](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataToolsPlatform/article.html)

which is completely different from anything else I have read (so far). You add the Oracle jdbc file to your Eclipse preferences. Nothing to do with your project. My pom.xml file is not longer red.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
      <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```